# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:

Tags: hibernate

ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING (IDBOOK, IDREADER) values (2, 2)' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to restart the server

Comment: you have to check the syntax of hql/sql query. might be possible query fields are not matched with table fields or there may be a possibility that table name or field name is not correctly mapped.

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception may occur if you have not created the table or view in the database. Check that the table exist in the database.

Comment: hibernate should be able to create the tables itself.